# How to get a callback from an external html page to the running GWT page?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I work on a simple logger-page enhancement. It being opened from main GWT module in a separate window by the invoking JSNI $wnd.open method.  What I want to get is that when I click a button (on the logger page) my main GWT's page gets notified. Is it possible to achieve? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for window.opener 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener

So have to define a function in your gwt app in JSIN native method:

```
$win.openerCallback = function(){};
```

and in your logger page:

```
window.opener.openerCallback()
```

to call the function in your gwt app

Comment: Thanks for replay. But it seems only work with Firefox, right?

Comment: it works smoothly with anonymous functions thanks! However is it possible to define func that pass args to my GWT app? I tried $wnd.openerCallback =  $entry(...) though in no way.

Comment: Mhmm, have you check out the JSNI doc: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling